# Beginner Importing in Dr. Java

Tags: java, import

Trying to import a class I made in Dr. Java. I made a simple class called `QuestionObject` which has `String questionString` and an array for answers and then an `int` which corresponds to the correct answer and corresponding getters, setters, and constructors. Compiles fine. In my other class file, the one with my main method and such called `Game`, when I try `import QuestionObject;` I get a 'cannot resolve' error in the compiler. I saved the class in the same folder as Game.java. Doing everything in OS X not using command line.

Help please! There's probably a simple answer, I just can't find it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't import the class if both classes are in the same directory and in the default package!
Try removing the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the package of both classes. And make sure that both classes are in the class path. I am not familiar with Dr Java but with the command line compiler javac *.java in the directory with the classes should pickup both classes.